# Understanding stat, du and ls -l output on my NFS mount

Tags: linux, filesystems, block-device, stat

```
ls -l f.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 abc abc 1161 Sep  1 02:02 f.txt

stat f.txt
  File: `f.txt'
  Size: 1161        Blocks: 34         IO Block: 524288 regular file
Device: 38h/56d Inode: 6448956669  Links: 1
Access: (0775/-rwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1024/   carle)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2017-09-09 02:02:36.000000000 -0700
Modify: 2017-09-09 02:02:36.000000000 -0700
Change: 2017-09-11 20:42:00.709807459 -0700

du -h f.txt
17K wiki.txt
```

1. Why is f.txt occupying 17K (17408 bytes) on disk?
2. What is IO Block size? Why is it 524288 bytes long and is not equal to filesystem block size (assuming file system block size is 17K)?

What's going on here?

Comment: What is block size of that partition, check size with `blockdev --getbsz <partition>`  command.

Comment: What is the filesystem type on the NFS server?  Offhand, it looks like the filesystem might start a file by allocating a 1KB block, and when that's exceeded it adds a 16KB block.  So your "1KB + a bit" file uses 17KB of disk space.

Comment: @abc Please share the output of `blockdev --getbsz <partition>` command.

Answer (score 1):

Neither,That's just confuse about `file size` vs `size on disk` on file system.
 [image: File System]
Here each box/block size is `17k` on file system, consider that yellow part is your file data (f.txt) which size is around 1161 but disk occupied 17k size full.`du` command give actual size on disk.

Assume that, your file size is `18000 bytes` then du command give the output 34k !

1. Size is the actual byte count of the file while size on disk is the actual byte count that it occupies on the disk.
2. Size on disk is usually bigger than the actual size of the file.
3. Size on disk can be smaller than the actual size for files that are marked sparse (have "holes") or automatically compressed by the filesystem.

Comment: 17KB is a weird block size for a filesystem, though.  I suspect the underlying filesystem might use dynamically-sized blocks - start with a 1KB block, then add a 16KB block.  It'd be interesting to see what happens in this case when file size does exceed 17 KB.